# VS 2022 CrystalReportView exception when dragged and dropped onto a form

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have Visual Studio 2022 and have just installed
SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (SP33) installation package for Microsoft Visual Studio IDE (VS 2022 and above).

I have shut down and re started the PC.

Started VS 2022 (as admin).
Created a new Windows Form App (.Net FrameWork) c#.
Dragged and dropped the CrystalReportsViewer from the ToolBox to the Form
[image]

But get this error message:-

[image]

Any ideas why?

Also why would I have 2 CrystalReportsViewer in the Tool Box, 1 Greyed out and 1 available to use?
[image]

tia